# kernel panic not syncing: vfs :unable to mount root fs on unknown block(31,1)

Tags: boot, embedded, kernel-panic, u-boot

I am trying to boot linux from flash on an powerpc board. In u-boot I set bootargs with:

```
setenv bootargs root=/dev/mtdblock1 rootfstype=ext2 rw console=ttyS0,115200 ramdisk_image=\${rd_size}
```

I also tried ***rootfstype=ext3*** and ***jfs2***; and ***root=/dev/mtdblockn*** (n from 0 to 6) and ***root=/dev/ram*** without rootfstype

The rd_size is another environment variable set to 12000.

Then each time I entered bootm with appropriate arguments, but each time I faced the error mentioned in title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the setenv command that ltib prints at the end of building images and the error vanished.
It seems that you should instruct system of size of your disk with that command.

setenv ramdisksize=90000,...